# Error on install Visual Studio 2012 Add-in in another computer

Tags: visual-studio-2012, menubar, visual-studio-addins, commandbar, vsinstaller

I made an add-in using VS 2012 and it works fine for me on debugging.
After done, I made a vsi installation file renaming a `zip` file that contains the `.addin`, `.dll` and `.vscontent` to `.vsi`
I'd sent this `vsi` file to another computer, and tried to install.
It's launch VS Content Installer and the installation ocurred with no problem.
But this addin creates a `commandbar` on `top-level menubar` `(Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommandBars.CommandBar)` and includes my addin commandbar inside it.
I'd made a shortcut in `Connect.cs` to call the addin using `ctrl + '`
This works fine for me too.
But in other computers, this don't work. The `top-level menu` and `commandbar` are not being created, as the shortcut that not works too.

Here is the link of VS with Menubar and Commandbar when are debugging.

http://s4.postimg.org/6j9ptli2l/image.png

Comment: You should post the image inside the question, links to external sites like this can disappear or be inaccessible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things to check:

If the user uses roaming profiles and/or has his VS add-in directory on a network drive / UNC path... ...the assemblies will not be trusted, and VS will fail to load the add-in.

Also make sure that they have the AddIn checked to load and run...

On the Tools menu, click Add-In Manager.

Is the Add-in registered to run with Visual Studio ?

Can you check that the Add-In dll is installed in the path you asked it to ?

(for locations: [See File Locations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19dax6cz.aspx))

Comment: Hey. Sorry for the delay. I upgrade from add-in to VSPackage and works for me. Thanks a lot